# React native - How to read dynamic form elements

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have dynamic form elements in the React page and I am not sure what is the best way to read all the input values to the state or any other possible solutions. Please suggest.

```
render() { 
 {
      answer.map((item) => {
        const code = item.code;
        const question = item.question;
        return (
          <View>
            <FormLabel labelStyle= {{
              color : '#000',
              fontSize: 20
            }}>{question}</FormLabel>

            <FormInput name={code} />

          </View> 
        );
      })
    }  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code works,

```
<FormInput name={code} onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({[code]: value})} />
```

Thanks,
Raja K